# Create row values in a column with data from previous row in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lag, shift

I am trying to create a new column in which the value in the first row is 0 and from the second row, it should do a calculation as mentioned below which is

```
ColumnA[This row] = (ColumnA[Last row] * 13 + ColumnB[This row])/14
```

I am using the python pandas shift function but it doesn't seem to be producing the intended result.

```
test  = np.array([ 1, 5, 3, 20, 2, 6, 9, 8, 7]) 
test = pd.DataFrame(test, columns = ['ABC'])
test.loc[test['ABC'] == 1, 'a'] = 0
test['a'] = (test['a'].shift()*13 + test['ABC'])/14
```

I am trying to create a column that looks like this

| ABC | a |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 0.3571 |
| 3 | 0.5459 |
| 20 | 1.9355 |
| 2 | 1.9401 |
| 6 | 2.2301 |
| 9 | 2.7137 |
| 8 | 3.0913 |
| 7 | 3.3705 |

But actually what I am getting by running the above code is this

| ABC | a |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | nan |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | nan |
| 4 | nan |
| 5 | nan |
| 6 | nan |
| 7 | nan |
| 8 | nan |
| 9 | nan |

Comment: Can you expand out the calculation for a given row?

Comment: Updated the numbers to have more decimal values

Comment: That wasn't my question. My understanding of `(ColumnA[Last row] * 13 + ColumnB[This row])/14` is that row 2 (0.3571) would be (1 * 13 + 5) / 14 which is 1.28 not 0.3571. _How_ are the values calculated?

Comment: Row 1 in Column['a'] from the table above would be 0. I would want to start with 0 in the first row so (0*13 + 5)/14 = 0.3571

Answer (score 0):

```py
test  = np.array([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) 
test = pd.DataFrame(test, columns = ['ABC'])
test["res"] = test["ABC"]
test.iloc[0]['res'] = 0                        # Initialize the first row as 0
test["res"] = test.res + test.res.shift() 
test["res"] = test.res.fillna(0).astype(int)   # test.res.shift() introduces a nan and we replace it with a 0 and convert the column data type to int
```

Comment: No this is just doing a sum of the last two rolling rows. If you see the table I have posted each row is a sum of previous row and the current column

Comment: Actually now modified the question to ask exactly what I wanted to do. Can you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
test["a"] = (test["ABC"].shift().cumsum() + test["ABC"].shift()).fillna(0)
print(test)
```

Prints:

```
   ABC     a
0    1   0.0
1    2   2.0
2    3   5.0
3    4   9.0
4    5  14.0
5    6  20.0
6    7  27.0
7    8  35.0
8    9  44.0
```

Comment: No this works if the number is in ascending order as I have put it. If you change the series to test  = np.array([ 1, 2, 8, 4, 9, 6, 7, 3 , 5]). The result will not be the same. I want to code to do a sum of a value in the previous row of the same column and the value in the same row from another column.

Comment: Actually now modified the question to ask exactly what I wanted to do. Can you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a for loop

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ABC': [1, 5, 3, 20, 2, 6, 9, 8, 7]})

lst = [0]
res = 0
for i, row in df.iloc[1:].iterrows():
    res = ((res * 13) + row['ABC']) / 14
    lst.append(res)

df['a'] = pd.Series(lst)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   ABC         a
0    1  0.000000
1    5  0.357143
2    3  0.545918
3   20  1.935496
4    2  1.940103
5    6  2.230096
6    9  2.713660
7    8  3.091256
8    7  3.370452
```

Comment: Actually now modified the question to ask exactly what I wanted to do. Can you please take a look at it?